# requset animation frame in java script

Tags: javascript

i have this code , it worked very well when i tested it in Khan Academy's code's section , but when i wrote it on code editors and tested it Chrome or Mozila it did not work !!

the HTML code :

```
 <img id="cat" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/misc/cat-walk.gif">
```

the java Script is :

```
<script>
 var catEl = document.getElementById("cat");

var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var walkTheCat = function() {
  var currTime = new Date().getTime();
  var secondsElapsed = ((currTime - startTime)/1000)*108;
  var newLeft = secondsElapsed+ "px";
   catEl.style.left = newLeft;
   window.requestAnimationFrame(walkTheCat);
 };
walkTheCat();
</script>
```

Comment: What's not working? Looks like that cat is walking. https://jsfiddle.net/3uLue4za/2/

Comment: i tried it on Chrome but it did not work !

Comment: It works just fine in Firefox for me (I'm at work and can't install chrome, I'll see if I can get a friend to test).  What are you seeing, what do you mean by, "did not work" ?

Comment: I tried it in Chrome as well and the cat is walking.  Am I missing something?